# App service certificate is not renewed despite of selecting rekey

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I did a rekey on my app service certificate, however the expiration time of my certificate has not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-keying an SSL certificate refers to creating a new private key for your certificate, which is used in the process of encrypting and decrypting data sent from and to your website.

Performing a re-key operation only gets a new key and has no effect on the expiration date. If you want to extend the expiration of the certificate, you need to renew it. You may also set the autorenew to true and the system will automatically renew the certificate.

PFB document that explains Rekey and sync certificate:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#rekey-and-sync-certificate

Comment: Now understand.  Thank you.